# How can I programmatically create DOM elements in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In React, I can do something like the following:

```
const childElements = [];

if (myCondition) {
  childElements.push(<div/>);
  childElements.push(<span/>);
}

...
return <div>{childElements}</div>
```

This is a very powerful technique when you're creating components with highly dynamic content.

Is there a way to do this in Vue 3? Or are you limited only to elements that appear in your template?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [Render functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html)

Comment: @Wolf Notice that this example is achievable with v-for and dynamic component. A compiled template is potentially more optimized than render function, not that this should be a decisive factor